# Why is apt-mark hold not stopping dkms from running on Debian?

Tags: apt, dkms

My `apt install id3v2` fails due to

```
dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.1.0-18-amd64.
```

with

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.11.2-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64
 linux-headers-6.1.0-18-amd64
 linux-image-amd64
 linux-headers-amd64
```

I've tried apt-mark hold linux-image-amd64 and have two holds

```
$ apt-mark showhold
linux-headers-amd64
linux-image-amd64
```

I am running 6.1.0-17-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.69-1 (2023-12-30) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Because that's triggered by `dpkg` doing postinst stuff, and `apt-mark hold` only holds for apt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [package hold](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/apt/apt-mark.8) doesn’t prevent packages which are already installed from being processed:

> hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the package from being automatically installed,
> upgraded or removed

In your case, `linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64` is already installed (at least partially), and it’s its configuration which tries to run `dkms` and fails.

Since you’re still running 6.1.0-17, the simplest solution for now is to remove 6.1.0-18:

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64
```

(which will also remove `linux-image-amd64`).

Once the failing `dkms` module is fixed, you’ll have to install `linux-image-amd64` again to upgrade your kernel.

If the failure is caused by NVIDIA drivers, that problem [has already been fixed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/769520/86440); you should upgrade the drivers instead of removing the kernel.

Comment: I had to remove the apt hold, and then purge the image and headers. Runing apt update upgrade doesn't install 6.1.0-18. Has it been pulled back or do I need to do something?

Comment: Did you re-install `linux-image-amd64`? An upgrade won’t pull in a new kernel without that.

Comment: I can install linux-image-amd64 but it doesn't update to 6.1.0-18, and linux-headers-amd64 fails.

Comment: [`linux-image-amd64`](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/linux-image-amd64) has a strong dependency on `linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64`, you can’t install it without also installing the new kernel. Have you fixed the failing `dkms` module? There’s no point in trying to install the new kernel image and headers if you don’t have a fixed `dkms` module.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems like this again with dkms you can stop the failing building until a fix for that is released. Note this is only a workaround not a solution.

Check with

```
dkms status
```

which module is concerned.

Then show under

```
/usr/src/name-of-whatever-pachage-which-version/dkms.conf
```

for the string

```
AUTOINSTALL="yes"
```

and change to no.
Do not forget to change it back after a bugfix; or you can long wait for building. :D