# debian 12 with nvidia graphic card, crash when going to google maps site

Tags: debian, nvidia

I installed debian 12 on a desktop with nvidia graphic gt1030. The driver 525.147.05 comes from the debian repository.

Every time I go to google maps (firefox or chromium) the system crashes and reboot. No problem with other sites.

I have not found relevant messages in `/var/log/syslog` or with `dmesg`.

I tried to uncheck graphic acceleration in firefox but same result.

```
sudo lspci | grep VGA
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] (rev a1)
```

I think it is the nvidia driver but how could I know for certain the origin of the crash?

I have not found information on this problem when googling. Is there a workaround?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151599/discussion-on-question-by-chris-debian-12-with-nvidia-graphic-card-crash-when-g); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

### Manual Install

After Doing a bit of research, I'd like to try downgrading your driver manually.  If this works we can also try upgrading the driver past the 525.47 version. Perform the following steps as root (`sudo -i`):

1. Detect the driver Debian would like to use - `nvidia-detect`.
2. Based upon the output of 1 (which should have reported `nvidia-driver` - 525.47.xx), download both that version and the previous version right above it  from the [NVIDIA Drivers Download Page for UNIX/Linux](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/)
3. Install the necessary tools needed to compile our own driver - `apt -y install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential libglvnd-dev pkg-config`
4. Disable the `nouveau` driver manually.  This may have already been done -

   - **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf**:

   ```
   blacklist nouveau
   options nouveau modeset=0
   ```
5. Update the RAM Disk - `update-initramfs -u`
6. Temporarily Stop the Graphical Login/ Desktop - `systemctl set-default multi-user.target && systemctl reboot`
7. After logging in as root or a regular user (`sudo -i`) - `cd /path/to/file/downloaded/in/Step2`
8. `bash NVIDIA-Linux-<Version>.run` a.k.a. `./NVIDIA + Tab Completion` - Select the version below what Debian Recommended first.
9. Complete the install - See [Step 7 under Manual Install](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/nvidia-drivers-debian), and answer those options accordingly.
10. Reenable the Graphical Login and Desktop - `systemctl set-default graphical.target && systemctl reboot`

If the above procedure works (and your issue disappears) with one driver version below what's in the repository, you've hit a regression bug that needs to be reported.  If you're satisfied that it works as intended, keep performing the above procedure using versions greater than what's in the repo (>525) and request a version bump in the same bug that you report the regression.  If the lower driver version fails, keep trying versions (<525) until it disappears.  If you try all the versions that support your card and it fails the issue is with webGL.

Comment: Hello,
As I said in the preamble, I'm new to linux and my skills are very limited. The manipulations you suggest are well documented and therefore probably obvious to someone with experience, but I've looked at them and I don't feel able to do them. Especially as I don't understand what most of them do. Just one example, what's the point of reinstalling linux-headers. On the other hand, you've already solved my problem, since I can now do what I want with Firefox. I understand if you're disappointed by my position, but I want you to know how much I appreciate the help you've given me.

Comment: @chris I'm not disappointed at all.  This answer is here in hopes it serves not only you but also other readers.  What you do with it is entirely up to you.  I wrote it because my first mid-range priced gaming system/linux /programmer system had a 1030Ti and a personal preference of `Chromium` usage in all the distributions I experimented with at the time.  The `nvidia-drivers` packages for all of them were around 400.xx.  If you'd like an explanation of what headers are or any other questions. I'd be happy to answer them, providing help along the way.

Comment: @chris See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769026/debian-12-linux-image-6-1-0-18-amd64-dist-upgrade-fails-on-nvidia-gpl-incompatib).  Please read my comments in the answer containing the patch.  This could or could not be related to your issue.  Also, now that I wrote it up in those comments, when comfortable try installing 525.60 using the steps I provided.

Comment: I have just updated my system. From the standard repo a new driver was installed 525.147.05-7. After reboot no change, firefox still ok with the modification on webgl and chrome still crashes the operating system. Also, with the previous driver, I had the problem when installing linux-image-6.1.0-18. So, I was back to 6.1.0-17. Now that a new driver is installed, the problem is supposed to be solved. Should I just install linux-image-6.1.0-18 or is there anything else to do (e.g. install linux-headers)?

Comment: You should actually: 1.) Upgrade the kernel, and 2.) Downgrade the `nvidia-driver` package to `525.60` using the instructions provided above.  The 525.147 driver was made around the time kernel 6.6 was released.  The Debian Kernel is currently at 6.1

Comment: To update the kernel, I think the command is apt install linux-image-6.1.0-18-amd64 and that's it. Am I wrong? Regarding the driver, I thought debian stable delivered a driver in line with the suggested kernel. I'm getting more and more confused.

Comment: Let me have you read: [Trunks and Trees](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/763608/64157).  Debian does release packages in line with most things, but the Debian Maintainer for the `nvidia-drivers` package is free to push/update the package he maintains whenever he feels it's appropriate.  Since in theory all NVIDIA Graphics Cards use a unified driver this is an acceptable approach.  The issue here is that in your particular case we may be dealing with a [software regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression) bug. I'm trying to find the driver where the regression doesn't occur.