# Wine doesn't work on Parrot, but it works on Pop OS

Tags: apt, wine, parrotsec

[image: Terminal Screenshot]I have a problem installing WINE on the Parrot distro which is based on Debian. I cannot install WINE from the official website, [WINE on Debian](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian), nor from the repository itself using `sudo apt install wine`. I and a beginner in Linux, and I really want to be able to make WINE work so I can play Dofus. It works on other distros like Pop OS, but this one is giving me headaches. I have already tried Flatpak with bottles, and when starting the game, it doesn't open. It just keeps loading, but it works fine on Pop OS.

I tried to install from the official repository, using the command `sudo apt install wine`. It installs. However, when it "complains" that it needs wine32, it warns that the packages are broken. I also tried using the steps on the official website, but it still doesn't work. I don't know what else to do. Can someone help me please?

Comment: See my answer below, but I must ask: Why are you installing WINE and playing Dofus on a Distribution made for cybersecurity and ethical hacking?

Comment: ahahah good question, I'm a curious student. and in addition to learning python, and js. I'm also interested in security, so I left it as the main one, and the only game I play is dofus. and I know that it works on pop os very well because I had it before.

Comment: @AdrianoAngioletto then… simply don't. It's no surprise that your security distro has not paid any attention to making games run, so the packaging of wine might simply not be compatible with it. So, run wine on pop os or plain debian. Honestly, it's not like parrot gives you anything you need: all the tools that you find in a parrot installation can be installed on debian, but not the other way around…

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you cannot install a package made for Debian in one of it's children.  Since WINE is a third-party package, the above general rule doesn't apply. Each OS has specific instructions on how to  install packages.  You were right to follow Debian's install page, but your issue here is you need to inform ParrotOS that you want to install a multilib package:

### Add Multilib Support

1. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

### Add Repository Key

1. `sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`

### Download the Repository List

1. `sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/dists/bookworm/winehq-bookworm.sources`

### Update And Install

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

Comment: I am at work right now. But I want to thank you with all my heart. for the time to help me. I'm from Brazil, and I'll test it as soon as I arrive. do I need to uninstall current wine? Will I get those broken package warnings? Thank you very much in advance. and forgive me because I'm a beginner in Linux.

Comment: I just did all the procedure you posted, but in the end it doesn't install because it says there is a broken package. And that's exactly the nightmare. I do not know what else to do. I posted the screenshot above.

Comment: Does the same error happen if you try `sudo apt install wine32`  Step 1 above implies `i386`.  If that doesn't work, I strongly agree with Marcus's comment above.  As an example see the [Parrot Security Github Repo](https://github.com/ParrotSec).  All Parrot is is a modified Debian 12 + the ability to pull packages/read from that repository

Comment: I was very discouraged with Linux, and I decided to go back to my Windows... my machine doesn't help to make things worse... but it's ok one day I'll come back, I'm grateful all the time... : (

Comment: @AdrianoAngioletto Read [Trunks and Trees](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/763597/how-to-install-package-versions-not-available-with-apt-get/763608#763608), and then start with plain Debian on an extra HDD/SSD, and learn about [dual-booting/multi-booting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-booting) which is where most Linux users  started. As you've seen thro experience now, its very tough fir gamers to quit Windows "cold turkey."